# Why don't we have to provide parentheses when initializing an array object in Java?

Tags: java, language-lawyer

I'm learning Java from the ground up right now, and one thing I found interesting was that most more complex data structures must be created in this fashion:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

On the other hand, one can simply initialize a string by typing

```java
String[] str_array = new String[10];
```

Why is it not necessary to provide the parentheses usually associated with calling the constructor when initializing an array? Was this just a stylistic choice? It would be awesome if someone with a better understanding of the JVM could offer some insight to sate my curiosity.

Comment: Are you asking about `String[] str_array = new String[10]();`

Comment: @RameshSubramanian yup i'm curious why there's no constructor called there

Comment: The syntax of Java has nothing to do with [tag:jvm]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: The answer here is 'because that's the way they designed it'.

Comment: @user207421 interesting. there has to be some justification out there somewhere though, right? someone had to decide to do this at some point despite the fact that arrays extend the object class.

Comment: Arrays are object

Comment: @user207421 also my bad i wasn't sure what to tag questions about syntax/what's behind decisions in a language

Comment: One can only speculate. But I know one thing. The more you dig the more you'll find inconsistencies and quirks in programming languages.

Comment: @J.D.Rudie *Why* should it be out there somewhere? Do you write down the reason for every decision you make every day? I thought not. Neither do language designers. You could try Arnold, Gosling, and Holmes, *The Java Programming Language,* all editions, but you won't find much in it of that nature. And two of these guys are the authors of Java.

Comment: @user207421 i mean i don't, but i'm also not making/maintaining a pretty big programming language. i feel like lots of other peculiarities like this have explanations: for instance, we know why the main method is always called with an array of String  arguments even though they're barely ever used, and other stuff like that. 

 i will have to get to reading that book at some point though, thanks for the rec.

Comment: Well the same rule applies in C++. It's not as though it's controversial. The extra `()` wouldn't add anything useful to either the compiler-writer or the programmer, or resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: Compare with `String[] str_array = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };` In short, arrays *are* special. Likewise, when declaring `enum Bla { FOO, BAR, BAZ }`, you also don’t need to specify the parentheses (though it’s a bit different as you *can* specify them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between object creation and array creation is this:

- normal classes have constructors that are called.

  - The parentheses in `new ArrayList<String>()` indicates the constructor call.
  - Even if a constructor has no arguments, the parentheses still have to be present (the same as in a method call without parameters).
- array classes on the other hand have no constructor

  - Although arrays are objects, their classes are created by the JVM and are therefore subject to special handling that other classes cannot have
  - Initializing the array happens as side effect of the `anewarray`, `multianewarray` and `newarray` bytecode instructions.

That array classes have no constructors can be demonstrated by executing

```
System.out.println(int[].class.getConstructors().length);
```

which returns 0.

---

In the end, this boils down to decisions the language designers made more than 20 years ago and that were influenced by design decision from other existing languages (like C++).

Comment: nice response! this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays can't be created in a same way as creating an ArrayList. As user207421 told , **"Arrays are designed to initialize in such a way by using []**". 
(e.g)

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList(); // It is valid

Arrays aArr = new Arrays();// It is invalid. Since there is no public constructor in java.util.Arrays
```

**Source Code :** http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java

C & C++ Languages uses the same [] for initialize an array. So that Java also following.

Comment: He is asking *why*, and `Arrays` has nothing to do with it.